# How to set combobox's value from extjs controller

Tags: combobox, controller, extjs4

I am working in extjs4. I have combobox with code as-

```
{
margin:'7 6 5 5',
xtype:'combobox',
fieldLabel:'Language',
name:'language',
id:'combo',
width:190,
allowBlank:false,
emptyText: '--Select language--',
labelWidth: 60,
store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: ['id','value'],
    data: [
        ['1','Marathi'],
        ['2','English']
    ]
}),
queryMode: 'local',
valueField:'id',
displayField:'value',
editable:false
},
```

Throuhout my functioning I want to set combobox's value defaultly to user's selected choice. So how to set combobox's value from controller

Comment: Aminesrine's answer is technically correct, but best practice would dictate that you not use an "id". It would be better to assign an itemId, or retrieve the instance of the combobox via a ComponentQuery.

Comment: Ya sir i am also trying same. i have written code as- id=Balaee.controller.qb.QbqnsController.ID;
   var getlanguageId =Ext.getCmp('combo'); 
   if(id==1)
   {
   
   getlanguageId.setValue('1','Marathi');
   }
   else
  {
     getlanguageId.setValue('2','English');
    }   But its setting value of combobox as[object HTMLDivElement]  So what i need to modify

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To select default value you can use event listener. After combobox has been rendered you can set value you need using [setValue()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-setValue) method from  [Ext.form.field.Field](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field) and if you need to select combobox value on demand you can get it using `Ext.getCmp('combo')` and then use [setValue()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-setValue) or even better set [itemId](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-itemId) instead of id and use [componentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) to fetch combobox and set value:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#combo')[0].setValue('2');
```

> **setValue( value ) : Ext.form.field.Field** Sets the specified value(s)
>   into the field. For each value, if a record is found in the store that
>   matches based on the valueField, then that record's displayField will
>   be displayed in the field. If no match is found, and the
>   valueNotFoundText config option is defined, then that will be
>   displayed as the default field text. Otherwise a blank value will be
>   shown, although the value will still be set.

```
listeners:{
    scope: this,
    afterRender: function(me){
        me.setValue('1');   
    }
}
```

### Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Tdq4t/2/) in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Ext.getCmp('combo').setValue('1' or '2');
```